# What are all intelligence agencies in Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek

United Federation of Planets has Section 31. Romulan Star Empire has Tal Shiar. Cardassian Union has Obsidian Order. Vulcans have V'Shar.

Do any of the **major powers** covered in detail in canon -- such as Klingons, Bajorans, Andorians, Ferengi -- basically, those that Starfleet has to deal with for more than one episode, have intelligence agencies mentioned?

Comment: List questions aren't really allowed, even though this isn't asking for a list of works. It's far too broad.

Comment: It really isn't that broad of a question. Most races encountered in Star Trek exist for only one episode and aren't likely to have known intelligence agencies.

Comment: @Xantec - I edited the question to make it much more restrictive so people can VTRO

Comment: This still to broad,  is the list given in the question all the races an answer should cover? How is the OP defining major powers?

Comment: For the record, Section 31 isn't an intelligence agency, it's a rogue (and covert) sabotage division much more closely akin to the likes of the Special Operations Executive - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Operations_Executive

Comment: @Pureferret I guess now its not too broad anymore. :)

Comment: Agree with @Richard - the "official" intelligence agency of the UFP is Starfleet Intelligence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are indeed some known intelligence agencies. Note, that due to the fact that there are several more agencies which are not stated in the series, but maybe in another cannon.

### On Earth, there were the intelligence agencies in history:

Most of them are only mentioned with sarcastic jokes in the series, rarely seen with uniforms:

- CIA *(TOS: "Assignment: Earth")*
- FBI *(TOS: "Assignment: Earth" + Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home)*
- Gestapo *(TOS: "Patterns of Force" + VOY: "The Killing Game" + ENT: "Storm Front" + short mentioned in TOS: "Mirror, Mirror")*
- KGB *(DS9: "Our Man Bashir" + mentioned in VOY: "Future's End")*
- MI5 *(DS9: "Change of Heart")*
- NSA *(TOS: "Assignment: Earth")*

### These three agencies are known in the Federation:

- Federation Security *(Star Trek III: The Search for Spock)*
- Starfleet Intelligence *(you'd better [see the hints here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_Intelligence), as they would create an really long list)*

  - Section 31 *(ENT: "Affliction", "Divergence", "Demons", "Terra Prime" + DS9: "Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges", "The Dogs Of War", "What You Leave Behind")*

### And for the other major powers, most of them nameless:

- Bajoran Intelligence *([several episodes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bajoran_Intelligence) in DS9)*
- Dominion Intelligence *(DS9: "To the Death", "Favor the Bold", "The Dogs Of War")*
- Idanian Intelligence *(DS9: "A Simple Investigation")*
- Klingon Intelligence *([several episodes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon_Intelligence) in TOS + DS9)*
- Obsidian Order *([several episodes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Obsidian_Order) in DS9)*

  - Cardassian Intelligence Bureau *(DS9: "Rocks and Shoals")*
- Tal Shiar (Romulan) *([several episodes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tal_Shiar) in TNG + DS9 + VOY)*
- V'Shar (Vulcan) *(TNG: "Gambit, Part II")*

If you want to know more about them, you should see the [list of intelligence agencies on Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Intelligence_agency), which contains further links.

Comment: Can you substantiate the "there are endless races in Star Trek" assumption?

Comment: Also, I edited the question to take it from "possibly large but finite list" to "a very short possible list" by restricting to major powers that are both covered in detail AND show up in >1 episode.

Comment: You may wish to improve your answer by also including the details that are relevant to the question, rather than just linking the page.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your thoughts of improvement! I hope I got it right. If not, please let me know. :)